# Rule to attach file when radio button selected

Tags: 2010, infopath

I would like to have my radio button selection have a rule that if you select Radio Button "A" you must attach a file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a validation rule to your file attachment field like this:

[image]

where `field2` is the radio button.